# How to make "hide this column" button

Tags: kendo-ui, hide, contextmenu, datagridcolumnheader

i have a grid in my kendo ui. I also have a header contextmenu on it. Now what i want to be able to do i. when i right click on the header and pick hide this column i want that column( on which it was right click was clicked) to hide.

Menu:

```
<ul class ="Menu" id="contextmenu" style=" display:none; position: absolute; background-color:white; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;" >
<li id="hideCol">Hide This Column</li>
<li>show hidden columns</li>
```

menu and hide this column functions:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $("table tr").bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            $("#contextmenu").css({ "top": event.pageY + "px", "left": event.pageX + "px" }).kendoMenu({ orientation: "vertical" }).show();
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $(document).bind('click', function() {
            $("#contextmenu").hide();
        });
    });

    $("#hideCol").click(function () {
        // Get reference to the Grid
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        // Get th cell index
        var idx = $("table tr").index();
        // Hide column
        grid.hideColumn(idx);
        //$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").hideColumn();

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your grid id is `grid`, what you need to do is find the index of the column and invoke `hideColumn`.

Assuming that `elem` is the table head (`th`) element where you right-clicked:

```
// Get reference to the Grid
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Get th cell index
var idx = $(elem).index();
// Hide column
grid.hideColumn(idx);
```

For seeing it in action, right click on the headers of the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/9x3H9/

Comment: I solved this table head problem, but it still dont work. Everything and wherever i do" hide this column" it only hide my column no 2 and then stop working.

Comment: I am sorry only hides the first column not no 2 as mentioned.

Comment: Could you share some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It in the post. I have just made an edit to the post.

Comment: As you have in the code added to the original question, it will not work because you have `$("#hideCol").click(function ()...` outside the `$(document).ready(function()...` which means that this is executed before KendoUI grid gets created. Try moving it inside!

Comment: I have done this change but still same result. Wherever I click it only removes first column. Here is the new(updated) code:

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hideCol").click(function() {
            
                // Get reference to the Grid
                var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
                // Get th cell index
                var idx = $("table tr").index();
                // Hide column
                grid.hideColumn(idx);

            });
        
        });

Comment: Is it possible for you showing a failing example in JSFiddle/JSBin. So I can debug it and (hopefully) fix it.

Comment: Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/gmBL9/ The problem is that the click was not bound to the table head so you don't know which column you are referring. You need to save the index when open the context menu.

Comment: This works perfectly. But when i changed the put this code is still dont work. Please check what am i doing wrong. Here is the link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gmBL9/1/

Comment: :-) typo error. You typed `var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");` in the function for hiding columns. `Grid` should be `grid`.

Comment: It's still not working. I dont know why. I changed from Grid to grid still nothing.

Comment: This is your JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/gmBL9/2/ where I just modified the `G` by a `g`. Does this work? It works on my computer / browser.

Comment: yes it works here in the fiddle for me too. But when i put in in my code in VS is does not work.

Comment: Unless you can reproduce it outside of you project I won't be able of helping you :-(